# How get method from another class method

Tags: php

I have two class es

```
class Pet {

    public $pet = null;

    public function setPet(){}

    public function getPet(){}
}
```

and

```
class B {

    public $cat = 'cat';
    public $dog = 'bog';

    public function cat()
    {
        $pet = new Pet();
        $pet->pet = $this->cat;
    }

    public function dog()
    {
        $pet = new Pet();
        $pet->pet= $this->dog;
    }
}
```

Can I get this:

```
$pet = new Pet();
$pet->setPet()->dog();

$pet->getPet(); //dog
```

Comment: You should consider having Class B extend Class Pet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My variant

```
class Pet {

public $pet = null;

public function setPet($pet = null)
{
    if (is_null($pet)) {
        return new B($this);
    } else {
        $this->pet = $pet;
        return $this;
    }
}

public function getPet()
{
    return $this->pet;
}
}

class B {

protected $pet = null;
protected $cat = 'cat';
protected $dog = 'bog';

public function __construct(Pet $pet)
{
    $this->pet = $pet;
}

public function cat()
{
    $this->pet->setPet($this->cat);
    return $this->pet;
}

public function dog()
{
    $this->pet->setPet($this->dog);
    return $this->pet;        
}
}

$pet = new Pet();
$pet->setPet()->cat();
var_dump($pet->getPet());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. You could make class B extends Pet. That will allow you to call the functions from the class Pet. Read up on object inheritance, that might help! http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extend Class Pet on Class B to call functions from the Pet class. So Class B inherits the functions of Pet.

```
Class B extends Pet {
    // class B functions here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I laughed while I'm writing down my code here..

```
<?php

class Pet {
        public $name;
        public function setName($string) {
            $this->name = $string;
        }
        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }
}

class Dog extends Pet {
        public function bark() {
            echo "Arf arf!";
        }
}

class Cat extends Pet {
        public function meow() {
            echo "Meoooww~ purrr~";
        }
}

$dog = new Dog();
$dog->setName("Jacob");
$dog->bark(); //Arf arf!
echo "Good job, ".$dog->getName()."!"; //Good job, Jacob!

?>
```

sir you cant call `$pet->setPet()->dog()` with `->dog()` since setPet() is a function and not an object.. just like they said, the right thing to do with your code is to extend it as a super class and declare a Dog Class as the child class..